# Can I ask developers of Stack Overflow to fill out a questionnaire?

Tags: discussion, survey, questionnaire

I am currently working on my thesis dealing with user feedback. For this I am conducting multiple studies and one of them is towards developers.

To do this I need several experiences and feedback from actual developers and since SO has quite a density of developers I wondered if I could just go there and ask. The problem is that it's not regarding programming directly.

Comment: Quite a few users have contact details on their profile. I've had requests for similar before (though tbh I always ignore them and don't know how successful these approaches are)

Comment: Closely related on MSE: [Academic studies and Stack Overflow community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188399)

Comment: If you actually have a budget for conducting research, you could always buy ad space.

Comment: Also, you can get some last year survey result form http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015. Which will helpful to you if any results required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've answered your question yourself: no, you can't. Stack Overflow only takes programming questions, not random surveys or social banter.

You *might* try some chat rooms and ask politely whether people there would like to participate in your survey, but how well that will be received will depend on the chat room.

You can also leave a link (and a short description) to your survey in your profile, and hope people see it there and follow up.